# Sharepoint Authentication (Windows and Forms) - User Mismatch

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, active-directory, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I've been doing some testing in sharepoint 2013 and I have come accross a rather annoying situation regarding the authentication. I have both windows authentication and forms authentication working. The forms authentication checks the creds against active directory on a DC.

The **scenario** in which I need both:

Windows; Fred logs in locally (internal) and is signed in automatically.

Windows; Fred logs in externally using an internal VM and is signed in automatically.

Forms; Bob is on an external network but has an internal active directory account. He then enters his internal AD creds.

The reason for this is that only users with an active directory account can access the site due to security.

**Problem Outline**

I have the following active directory account:
Username - User1
Fullname - User Name
Password - Monkey

So if I log into sharepoint using windows authenication it will recognise me as "Name, User", the issue arrises when the same user logs in via forms. It recognises the same account as "User1".

How can I get round this?

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? We're having the same issue and are still trying to find a working solution.

Comment: See my answer :) I hope it sorts your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a lot of searching and blog reading the unfortunate solution I have come up with is that it's not possible for our network.

Basically, sharepoint does not or cannot connect profiles from two different authentication models.

There is however a work around. [ADFS](http://sharepointobservations.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/sharepoint-2013-how-to-install-and-configure-adfs-2-0/) offers both windows automatic sign on and forms sign on thus sharepoint thinks it's only using one provider. This would solve the question raised, unfortunalely it doesn't solve my issue because ADFS is incompatible with our infastructure.

I hope this helps :)